# Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: this.search_result is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: this.search_result is not a function" error when I'm trying to call a function which is defined in the same file. I'm calling it in the render part of my react app. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong over here. How can I solve this and call the function?

My code is:

```
    export default class Search extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {results: []};
    }

    search(string){
        client.search({
            index: 'tweet',
            type: 'tweet',
            size: 1000,
            body: {
                query: {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {"match": {"text": string}},
                            {"match": {"user_id": string}},
                            {"match": {"date": string}}
                        ]
                    }
                },
            }
        }, (error, response, status) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("search error: " + error)
            }
            else {
                console.log("--- Response ---");
                console.log(response);
                console.log("--- Hits ---");
                response.hits.hits.forEach(function (hit) {
                    let re1 = new RegExp("((#|@)([A-Za-z0-9]+))", "g");
                    hit._source.text = hit._source.text.replace(re1, ("<a href='javascript:this.search(/"$&/");'>$&</a>"));
                    this.setState({results: this.state.results.concat([hit._source])})
                }.bind(this)
                );    
            }
        })
    }
    handleKeyPress = (event) => {
        if(event.key === 'Enter'){
            event.preventDefault();
            const search_query = event.target.value;
            this.state.results=[];
            this.search(search_query);

        }
    };

    render() {

        return(
            <Linkify>
                <div>
                    <input className={"search-bar"} type="text" onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress.bind(this)}>
                    </input>

                    <div>{this.state.results.map((results, index) => (
                        <p key={index} className={"result"}><span className={"date"}>{results.date}</span> <span>&nbsp;</span>
                            <span className={"user_id"}>{results.user_id}</span> <span>&nbsp;</span>
                            <span>{ Parser(results.text) }</span>
                        </p>
                    ))}</div>


                </div>
            </Linkify>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error when I'm calling "search" in this part                                     "<a href='javascript:this.search($&);'>$&</a>" which is returning "this.search(@nytnow);"

Comment: Error is that only. @PatrickEvans $& is returning the regex match and that is working fine.

Comment: @JaromandaX having `handleKeyPress` as an arrow function is fine; it is a class property and prevents the boilerplate binding of `this`

Comment: Oh didn't see the regex replacement

Comment: @JaromandaX this.search in <handleKeyPress> is working fine but that is not working when I'm calling it in href.

Comment: `@nytnow` is also not a valid variable name either, unless that is going under some other replacement, did you mean to wrap it in quotes?

Comment: @JaromandaX it definitely won't be wrong - see http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html or numerous other resources

Comment: handleKeyPress (event) => { is working perfectly fine without giving any error.

Comment: @PatrickEvans  I need to pass it as a String. I guess that's why it is giving error. How can I fix that? appending quotes to it or is there any cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Something along the lines of `this.search(\"$&\")`

Comment: @JaromandaX I fixed that.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Now I'm getting " Uncaught TypeError: this.search is not a function "

Comment: Since you are using inline js call from a href `this` isn't probably going to reference your react component, you should be using the `onClick=` handler and point it to your search function. See [Handling Events document](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) and the [Passing Arguments in Event Handlers section](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers)

Comment: @PatrickEvans I'm using html-react-parser to parse the variable with html body and that is not passing any other attribute than href.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I tried using onClick= but in this case that is not returning anything.